# React Get state of native elemet

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making my custom components that wrap react-native components. I am currently making MyInput component. It uses TextInput component.I want to know state of TextInput component, but i dont want to use onFocus or onBlur etc. I am trying to pass all of those props trough. I am currently trying with using refs, but it is not working properly because there is delay. "isFocused" only turns true when I start typing, not on click. Is there some good way to solve this?

```
interface InputProps extends TextInputProps {
}
export const Input = ({
  children,
  ...props
}: PropsWithChildren<InputProps>) => {
  const { themeStyles } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { styles } = useStyles(themeStyles);
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
  const isFocused = inputRef.current?.isFocused(); // not working properly
  return (
    <View style={[styles.inputContainer]}>
      <TextInput ref={inputRef} {...props} style={[styles.input, isFocused && styles.blueText]}>
        {children}
      </TextInput>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest with you, I don't see a good way of doing this without using `onFocus` and `onBlur`. Your `isFocused` variable is only updating when your component re-renders, which is why you're seeing the behavior you don't like.

You could try this, but I'm not sure that it's ideal or will generate the desired results:

```
export const Input = ({
  children,
  ...props
}: PropsWithChildren<InputProps>) => {
  const { themeStyles } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { styles } = useStyles(themeStyles);
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
  // const isFocused = inputRef.current?.isFocused(); // not working properly

  return (
    <View style={[styles.inputContainer]}>
      <TextInput ref={inputRef} {...props} style={[styles.input, inputRef.current?.isFocused() && styles.blueText]}>
        {children}
      </TextInput>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I don't know what your restrictions are, but based on your description, I might try merging the `onFocus` and `onBlur` props passed to `Input` with internal functions that set the desired styles. Something like this:

```
export const Input = ({
  children,
  onFocus,
  onBlur,
  ...props
}: PropsWithChildren<InputProps>) => {
  const { themeStyles } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { styles } = useStyles(themeStyles);
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

  const [focusedStyle, setFocusedStyle] = useState(undefined);
  
  const onInputFocus = useCallback((e) => {
    onFocus(e);
    setFocusedStyle(styles.blueText);
  }, [onFocus]);
  const onInputBlur = useCallback((e) => {
    onBlur(e);
    setFocusedStyle(undefined);
  }, [onBlur]);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.inputContainer]}>
      <TextInput ref={inputRef} {...props} style={[styles.input, focusedStyle]} onFocus={onInputFocus} onBlur={onInputBlur}>
        {children}
      </TextInput>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Alternatively, have you considered using a library like [React Native Paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/TextInput/)? It's `TextInput` component handles this for you, and exposes props for both focused/unfocused styling.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I used second approach in the end. I just wanted to check if there is other way, because this seems like common pattern in react and kinda seems like we are using unnecessary state for something that already has state variable inside.